# The app theme doesn't load correctly if it differs from the system theme

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme, android-dark-theme

I have a problem where I have two themes in my app. Dark theme, and Light Theme

The problem is that the app theme doesn't load correctly if I set the app theme to be different from the system theme.

The Light theme inherits from:

```
<style name="Theme.Light" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

and the Dark Theme inherits from:

```
<style name="Theme.Dark" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar">
```

e.g. if the system theme is light and the app theme uses a dark theme that inherits from 
'Theme.MaterialComponents.NoActionBar' 
then the theme will not render correctly and vice versa.

I'm using values-night directory which holds all the colors used in the dark theme.

Comment: If You are using values-night then You should probably have one Theme that has a parent of "Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight". Look at this article: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/appcompat-v23-2-daynight-d10f90c83e94

Comment: I tried this and it caused issues selecting the correct background color. 
I fixed the problem by forcing the app to go to night mode if the currently set theme is dark.

Comment: In DayNight case the problem can be the declaration of colors in styles.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed the problem by setting the app to switch theme modes depending on the app theme.

```
fun setTheme(){
        if(getThemeRes() == R.style.Theme_Dark){
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
        }
        else{
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
        }
    }
```

A function that returns an Integer resource containing the currently set theme.

```
fun getThemeRes() = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
        packageName,
        PackageManager.GET_META_DATA
    ).applicationInfo.theme
```